# Postgres CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW... can it block?

Tags: postgresql, locking, view, concurrency, blocking

I'm looking for a way for a table to be swapped *while* it's being used. Say we have a view

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_data AS SELECT * FROM my_data_v1;
```

that is being used, e.g. lots of `SELECT * FROM my_data`. Then I ingest data into a new table, `my_data_v2`, and then run:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_data AS SELECT * FROM my_data_v2;
```

Would this block on any `SELECT` statements that are using the original view definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that would block, and there is no way around that.